# failed to write right values to pointer of typedef array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My problem is the following - I have this lines of code:

```
// allocate a new vector
        Vector3I *theVector = (Vector3I*)calloc(1,sizeof(Vector3I));

        // write face's points to this vector
        *theVector[0] = a3dsFace->points[0];
        *theVector[1] = a3dsFace->points[1];
        *theVector[2] = a3dsFace->points[2];
```

In the `points[]` array are the values `{0,1,2}`. When I write them to the `Vector3I` at which I am pointing to I get `{0,0,0}`. Do you have any suggestions about what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Some more details:

This is from lib3ds at: http://code.google.com/p/lib3ds/

```
struct Lib3dsFace {
    Lib3dsUserData user;    /*! Arbitrary user data */
    char material[64];      /*! Material name */
    Lib3dsWord points[3];   /*! Indices into mesh points list */
    Lib3dsWord flags;       /*! See Lib3dsFaceFlag, below */
    Lib3dsDword smoothing;  /*! Bitmask; each bit identifies a group */
    Lib3dsVector normal;
};
```

The `a3dsFace` is a `Lib3dsFace` struct.

And the points array is from this type:

```
 typedef unsigned __int16 Lib3dsWord
```

And my Pointer:

```
Vector3I* theVector
```

is

```
typedef int Vector3I[3];
```

I hope this will bring some light to the problem.

With kind regards.

Comment: What is `Vector3I` ? What is `a3dsFace->points` ?

Comment: Hi, Vector3I is: typedef int Vector3I[3]; and points: Lib3dsWord points[3]; where typedef unsigned __int16 typedef unsigned __int16 Lib3dsWord;

Comment: add the definitions of both typedefs to your question please.  I can't make out the definitions from your comment.

Comment: @Knut: Post a working code example, that also includes the definition of `a3dsFace` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code *does* work and is a test of your code snippet. If something isn't working, it could be a good idea to create a test like this, with hard-coded values for `*a3dsFace`, in order to narrow down your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int Vector3I[3];
typedef uint16_t Lib3dsWord;

struct Lib3dsFace {
   /* ... */
   Lib3dsWord points[3];   /*! Indices into mesh points list */
   /* ... */
};

/* ... */
struct Lib3dsFace some_face = { {0, 1, 2} };
struct Lib3dsFace *a3dsFace = &some_face;
/* ... */

int main(void)
{
   Vector3I *theVector = (Vector3I*)calloc(1,sizeof(Vector3I));

   (*theVector)[0] = a3dsFace->points[0];
   (*theVector)[1] = a3dsFace->points[1];
   (*theVector)[2] = a3dsFace->points[2];

   printf("theVector: %p, *theVector: %p, &(*theVector)[0]: %p\n", theVector, *theVector, &(*theVector)[0]);

   printf("RIGHT Addresses: %p, %p, %p\n", &(*theVector)[0], &(*theVector)[1], &(*theVector)[2]);
   printf("WRONG Addresses: %p, %p, %p\n", &*theVector[0], &*theVector[1], &*theVector[2]);

   printf("Values: %d, %d, %d\n", (*theVector)[0], (*theVector)[1], (*theVector)[2]);

   free(theVector);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
theVector: 0x1cd3010, *theVector: 0x1cd3010, &(*theVector)[0]: 0x1cd3010
RIGHT Addresses: 0x1cd3010, 0x1cd3014, 0x1cd3018
WRONG Addresses: 0x1cd3010, 0x1cd301c, 0x1cd3028
Values: 0, 1, 2
```

I put the addresses there so that you can see `(*theVector)[0]` is a valid way of accessing the first element of your dynamically allocated `Vector3I`.

Perhaps you haven't set `a3dsFace->points` properly and that's why `{0, 0, 0}` is being copied. Note also that you have each element of a `Vector3I` as type `int`, and each point is of type `uint16_t`. You also don't need to use `calloc` to zero the allocated memory, since you're immediately after assigning values to them; you could just use `malloc`.

Bottom line is you still haven't provided enough code to find your exact problem, and you should add code to debug your code inside your code.

**EDIT:** I accidentally had `*theVector[0]` which should have been and is now `(*theVector)[0]`, since `[]` has higher precedence than `*`. Otherwise it'd cause undefined behaviour due to the fact you're going past the bounds of the array, my bad. I don't know how I forgot that when it was one of the main reasons I was going to post an answer before you made your edit. It worked, but if you ran it through a program like valgrind it'd tell you that something wasn't quite right (even if it may have ran as expected).

As you can see by the addresses outputted above, there's quite a difference. For example having `*theVector[1]`, which because of operator precedence is the same as `*(theVector[1])`, will mean that it'll increment the address pointed to by `theVector` by `3 * sizeof(int)` bytes (aka `sizeof(Vector3I)`), instead of just `1 * sizeof(int)` in the (correct) case of `(*theVector)[1]`).

Comment: What you are doing is undefined. You are allocating space for an array of size of 3 ints, and are accessing way beyond that. Operator precedence is [] and then *.

Comment: @Milan: Woops it is too - I actually had that in the example I was going to post before he made his edit and missed that in the new example. It seemed to work in this case, but as you say it's not right (should've run this example in valgrind as well to catch that). I knew I was forgetting something when I posted, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Oh the braces! I didnt know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try this (note allocate 3 elements and access with just array notation):

```
Vectore3I *theVector = (Vector3I*)calloc(3, sizeof(Vector3I));

theVector[0] = a3dsFace->points[0];
theVector[1] = a3dsFace->points[1];
theVector[2] = a3dsFace->points[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
// allocate a new vector
        Vector3I *theVector = calloc(1,sizeof(Vector3I));

        // write face's points to this vector
        (*theVector)[0] = a3dsFace->points[0];
        (*theVector)[1] = a3dsFace->points[1];
        (*theVector)[2] = a3dsFace->points[2];
```